# Display a message when a multiselect dropdown in office ui fabric is collapsed

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Is there a way to know when a multiselect dropdown is collapsed? I have a multiselect dropdown as show here:

[image: Multi Select Dropdown] 
On unselecting all options, the dropdown still remains expanded as shown in the above image. On clicking somewhere else in the screen outside dropdown, it collapses. I need to perform some actions (for example, display a message) when dropdown collapses. Is there a way to know when a multiselect dropdown is collapsed?

I was able to use onBlur instead. But, I need to click outside Dropdown twice in order to print the message.

```
<Dropdown
options={[
{ key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
{ key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
{ key: 'C', text: 'Option c' }
]}
multiSelect={true}
onBlur={this.onFilterDropDownDismiss}
/>

private onFilterDropDownDismiss = (): void => {
console.log("Dismissed");
}
```

But, I need to display the message on one click outside. Please let me know if there are any suggestions to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`IDropdownProps.onDismiss` event could be utilized for that matter:

> Callback issues when the options callout is dismissed

```
<Dropdown
      options={[
        { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
        { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
        { key: 'C', text: 'Option c' }
      ]}
      multiSelect={true}
      onDismiss={this.onFilterDropDownDismiss}
    />


private onFilterDropDownDismiss = (): void => {    
   console.log("Dismissed");
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0p6nvo6xjw) for your reference

Comment: Thank you. I get the error "onDismiss property doesn't exist when I use it. Please refer https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/6345 for more details. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, what version of office-ui-fabric are you using?

Comment: I’m using 4.43.1

Comment: I was about to propose the same, IDropdownProps.onDismis event was introduced in  later version